# How to incorporate an input array in this program

Tags: c, arrays

This is a code that has to take an input array from the user and input the same after removing the duplicates. However, I am unsure on how to incorporate an input array in this, and right now it has the elements hardcoded. This is my first week of programming so I apologize if this is a silly question. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define nelems 8
int main()
{
    int l[nelems] = {1,2,3,1,4,4,5,6};    

    for(int m=0;m<nelems;m++)
    {
        bool wase = 0;
        for(int n=0;n<nelems && m>n;n++)          
        {
            if (l[m] == l[n] && m != n)
                wase = 1;
        }
        if (wase == 0){
            printf("%d\n", l[m]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n<nelems && m>n` is not required in the nested for loop, just `n<m` or `m>n` is enough because `m` is always `< nelems`

Comment: The question that is not apparent from your question is "What do you want to do with the user array if you *find duplicates*? Is this capture of user data the result of the user typing it in as the code is running?, or can this data be read from a data-file? If from user, just cycle-through all previous entries with the value he typed and if it is *non-unique*, prompt for correction. If the data is from a file, then you either reject the entire dataset of 'smooth' the value in some acceptable way such that it will continue to allow your code to execute. Without knowing the circumstance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define nelems 8
int main()
{
    int i;
    int l[nelems] ;
    for(i=0;i<nelems;i++)
    {
       printf("enter %d number :",i);
       scanf("%d",&l[i]);
    }

    for(int m=0;m<nelems;m++)
    {
        bool wase = 0;
        for(int n=0;n<nelems && m>n;n++)          
        {
            if (l[m] == l[n] && m != n)
                wase = 1;
        }
        if (wase == 0){
            printf("%d\n", l[m]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a for loop and scanf.

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<nelems;i++){
    scanf("%d",&l[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like int-type array, you can just declare another one:

```
int input[nelems];
```

and follow the user968000 advice, remembering that when you are typing the sequence in your console you have to put a white space between each number.
To avoid that, I'd rather use char-type arrays, declared as follows:

```
char l[nelems] = {'1', '2', '3' /*etc.*/};
char input[nelems];
```

Then you make a **for** loop, as user968000 suggested:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<nelems;i++)
  scanf("%c", &input[i]);
```

In this case you won't need the white spaces between the digits. Notice the '&' character in the scanf function: just put it as I showed, you'll surely learn what it is in next lessons.

So you have an input array and you can handle it as you want.